# Why C# PowerShell.Create() returns null in case of .NET Core?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, asp.net-core, .net-core

I have library built for .NET Standard 2.0.

I am using this library in

- a .NET Core project and
- a .NET Framework project.

I have integrated this [PowerShellStandard.Library](https://www.nuget.org/packages/PowerShellStandard.Library/) (Version 5.1.0) nuget into my .NET Standard library. It is used to fetch some date which is connected to PC.

```
private string RunPowerShellCommand(string paramValue)
{
    using (PowerShell powershell = PowerShell.Create().AddCommand("Get-PnpDeviceProperty").AddParameter("InstanceId", paramValue).AddParameter("KeyName", "DEVPKEY_Device_Parent"))
    {
        var result = powershell.Invoke();
        string deviceId = "";
        foreach (var r in result)
        {
            var properties = r.Properties;

            var device = (string)properties.Where(t => t.Name == "Data").FirstOrDefault().Value;
            deviceId = (string)device;
        }
        return deviceId.Split('\\')[2];
    }
}
```

- When I call above code from the .NET Framework project then the `PowerShell.Create()` returns the proper PowerShell object
- When I call same code from the .NET Core project then it returns `null`.

Could anyone me please ?!

Comment: Is Powershell Core installed? Which version? The version you installed is rather old

Comment: In any case, Powershell Core is a .NET Core shell while Windows PowerShell is .NET Framework. You're trying to load .NET Old assemblies in a .NET Core application. The package's description says `Enable same Module to support PowerShell Core and Windows PowerShell`, not that you can load Windows PowerShell into a .NET Core applicatino

Comment: You can solve the 'null return' problem by adding the [PowerShell SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.PowerShell.SDK) to your project, but you may still get nothing from the PNP cmdlets in .NET Core - some things [just aren't supported](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62835479/function-ported-from-powershell-5-to-powershell-7-fails-with-object-reference-n/62835701#62835701) in the newer PS versions.

Comment: What does `powershell.HadErrors` and the contents of `powershell.Streams.Error` tell you? :)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I did not install powershell core in among three projects. could you please let me know Powershell Core nuget package. in which project we need to install?.

Comment: Powershell and Powershell Core are *shells*, not packages. You need to [install Powershell Core on the machine itself](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows?view=powershell-7) before you host it in your application